# I cant get link_to work with POST in my rails app. What am I missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie doing Ruby on Rails and I have this code in my html.erb file:

```
<%= link_to 'Add to portfolio', user_stocks_path(user: current_user, ticker: @stock.ticker), method: :post %>
```

This translates to this in the page source when rendered:

`<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success logout-btn" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/user_stocks?ticker=amzn&amp;user=2">Add to portfolio</a>`

But when I click on this the error is :

`No route matches [GET] "/user_stocks"`

Why is it not posting but doing a get? Please advise. I am on Rails 7.0.4.3

Comment: Can you add your `routes.rb` to the description? 
And the result of `rails routes|grep stock` would help a lot.

Comment: + Are you using `Turbo`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create form with button with `button_to`

```
<%= button_to 'Add to portfolio', user_stocks_path(user: current_user, ticker: @stock.ticker), method: :post %>
```

Or link with JS-magic. In rails 7 with Turbo you need apply `data-turbo-method="post"` attribute

```
<%= link_to 'Add to portfolio', user_stocks_path(user: current_user, ticker: @stock.ticker), data: { turbo_method: :post } %>
```